# Unusual CString formatting

Tags: c++, c

I have such code:

```
int value = 65536;

CString output = TEXT("");
output.Format(TEXT("%X"), value);
```

Printing `output` gives me: `10000`

I need output like this: `0001.0000`

Is it possible?

Comment: You're printing the hex value of `65536`, which is `0x10000` correctly being dispalyed. Why are you trying to print `0001.0000`? What is the rule to the format you want to print ?

Comment: @storojs72 You should read up on format specifiers.The number of digits printed can be specified by the precision parameter. Also you will have to split up the number into the low and high part if you really need to have them separated by a point.

Comment: @naffarn I get responce from hardware that version of firmware is (for example) 0001.0000. And I need to inform user about this

Comment: Use %04X.%04X and split the number into two parts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me I have found answer:

```
output.Format(TEXT("%.4X.%.4X"), (value >> 16) & 0xffff, value & 0xffff);
```

Comment: You can use the `HIWORD()` and `LOWORD()` macros instead of manual bit shifting. And you should use `%.4hu` instead of `%.4X`: `output.Format(TEXT("%.4hu.%.4hu"), HIWORD(value), LOWORD(value));` I wonder, though, why you would want to show the version number as `0001.0000` instead of a more human-friendly `1.0`? `output.Format(TEXT("%hu.%hu"), HIWORD(value), LOWORD(value));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to mast byte you don't want and leave all others.

Assuming int is 32 bits on your platform you have:

```
Byte         4           3           2           1
Binary | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0001 | 0000 0000 |
Hex         0x00        0x01        0x00        0x00
```

What you want is to isolate byte 1-2 and byte 3-4

- Byte 1-2: simply mask all others bits using 0x0000FFFF or simply 0xFFFF
- Byte 3-4: move left for 16 byts of bytes 1-2. Not your case but to be sure to print only value of those bytes mask all other bits.

Your code can be:

```
output.Format(TEXT("%04X.%04X"), (value >> 16) & 0xFFFF, (value & 0xFFFF));
```

Answer (score -1):

> Printing output gives me: 10000

The "%X" format string works just as expected.

> I need output like this: 0001.0000

If I might ask, what's the point of using a floating point decimal representation? Hexadecimal is used because it translates directly to binary, otherwise there's no point using it.

But anyway if you really need it, the [CString::format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327(v=vs.60).aspx)'s formatting string is the same as [printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)'s:

> %A Hexadecimal floating point, uppercase

So replace %F by %A and cast your variable as a float it should do the trick!

Comment: _The `%a` formatting specifier is new in `C99`. It prints the floating-point number in hexadecimal form._   It isn't what OP is asking for.

Comment: So what?. OP asked for a way to print (I assume) an floating point number in hexadecimal, which is what %a does.